# Accordion events not firing

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

I have alerts that should fire on 'activate' and 'beforeActivate' events. Neither of these occur.

Javascript

```
$(function () {
  $(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: false,
    active: true,
    activate: function (event, ui) { alert("activate"); },
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) { alert("before activate"); }
  });
});
```

Html

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>0</li>
    <div class="accordion">
        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>3</li>
                    <li>4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am aware of my incorrect html in nesting div in side of ul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you make sure and include the proper reference to the [**jQueryUI**](http://www.jqueryui.com) library?

**CDN**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js'></script>
```

**Normal File Reference**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../yourDirectory/jquery-ui.js'></script>
```

You can see a working example below, which functions properly after including the jQuery UI reference.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8SAkh/)**

Comment: I am using jquery-ui-1.8.11

Comment: It appears to be an issue with 1.8.11, as I attempted to use 1.8.1 and it failed to work. Is upgrading to 1.9.1 an option, as it looks as though it may be a bug with < 1.9

Answer (score 14):

If you're using 1.8, then you want to use `change` and `changestart` as the events:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
    change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/accordion

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to figure out why `activate` would not work.

Answer (score 1):

`activate` and `beforeActivate` events do not exist in jQuery UI 1.8, which explains why the alerts are not firing.

As mentioned by Shaz,
In jQuery UI 1.8, these events are named `change` and `changestart`.

> https://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/accordion/

Starting from jQuery UI 1.9, the events name changed to `activate` and `beforeActivate`.

> https://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/accordion/

Further details:

> http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.9.0/#accordion
>   `Deprecated: changestart event; renamed to beforeActivate. (#6840, 088ef05, e0fe788)`
>   `Deprecated: change event; renamed to activate. (#6842, 088ef05, e0fe788)`